# On click remove if already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Hello everyone I'm trying to add a onclick script but I dont know how to start it.

Right now I'm able to pull the data out of a row from a table using this script and saving the values as a new object of data but if I click the same row again it's gonna add the same data over and over again, how can I add a condition where if the row that I selected is exists it can't be added or remove if I click it again?

```
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">



    <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="myTableData">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>val5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td>val5</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<script>
    init();
    function init(){

        addRowHandlers('myTableData');

    }

    function addRowHandlers(tableId) {
        if(document.getElementById(tableId)!=null){
            var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var A = "";
            var B = "";
            var C = "";
            var D = "";
            function Registro(A, B, C, D, E) {
                            this.A = A;
                            this.B = B; 
                            this.C = C; 
                            this.D = D;
                            this.E = E;
                        };
            var total_registros = [];
            var total_registros = total_registros.filter(o=> o.A != A);
            for ( var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

                rows[i].i = i;
                rows[i].onclick = function() {
                    A = table.rows[this.i].cells[0].innerHTML;                
                    B = table.rows[this.i].cells[1].innerHTML;
                    C = table.rows[this.i].cells[2].innerHTML;
                    D = table.rows[this.i].cells[3].innerHTML;
                    E = table.rows[this.i].cells[4].innerHTML;
                    var newRegistro = new Registro(A, B, C, D, E);
                    total_registros.push(newRegistro);
                    console.log("-Log- New data", total_registros);
                };
            }
        }
    }
</script>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the event handler for that row after it has been clicked.
Additionally, you'll need to change your looping variable declaration from using `var` to using `let` to avoid a closure around `i`.

See comments inline:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">



    <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="myTableData">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>val5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td>val5</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<script>
    init();
    function init(){

        addRowHandlers('myTableData');

    }

    function addRowHandlers(tableId) {
        if(document.getElementById(tableId)!=null){
            var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var A = "";
            var B = "";
            var C = "";
            var D = "";
            function Registro(A, B, C, D, E) {
                            this.A = A;
                            this.B = B; 
                            this.C = C; 
                            this.D = D;
                            this.E = E;
                        };
            var total_registros = [];
            var total_registros = total_registros.filter(o=> o.A != A);
            
            // Use let instead of var to avoid a closure around the looping variable
            for ( let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

                rows[i].i = i;
                rows[i].onclick = function() {
                    A = table.rows[this.i].cells[0].innerHTML;                
                    B = table.rows[this.i].cells[1].innerHTML;
                    C = table.rows[this.i].cells[2].innerHTML;
                    D = table.rows[this.i].cells[3].innerHTML;
                    E = table.rows[this.i].cells[4].innerHTML;
                    var newRegistro = new Registro(A, B, C, D, E);
                    total_registros.push(newRegistro);
                    console.log("-Log- New data", total_registros);
                    // Now remove the handler because the job is done
                    rows[i].onclick = null;
                };
            }
        }
    }
</script>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, works like a charm I can't stop thanking you really :D , <3 Cheers

Comment: @IceeFrog You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of the answer.

Comment: Was waiting for the 10minutes delay, marked it as answer, thanks again Mr Scott :D

Answer (score 0):

Add variables previousRow and a currentRow. Inside onclick function check if the currentRow and previousRow are same or not. If both are same don't do anything. If both are different push it to the array.